# Protobuf webservice deserialization in vba

Tags: web-services, rest, vba, interop, protocol-buffers

In my organisation I would like to implement a rest web service with protobuf serialization that seems to me being the best, due to performance constraints. It is a java implementation hosted in a web server.
On client side (that I do not manage and won't develop), we have constraints too: XLS with VBA, not VB.Net (can not change it)

So my questions are:

- Does this architecture fit? Specially how to manage the interoperability and the serial/deserial in vb for xls? How to manage the .proto, would you have a sample?
  Does it seem possible?
- In case it does not work, (or too difficult or time consuming) any idea? (JSON, SOAP) considering this client techno constraint and the fact I would like something very performant/fast?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a non-.NET VB/VBA implementation. You would either have to write one, or choose from the list of [existing implementations](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns). Or choose a different serialization technology, but frankly VBA isn't exactly awash with those.

Do you have .NET on the client? If you can use COM interop to call into .NET code then you'll have much more flexibility, including multiple protobuf implementations to choose from.

Comment: Tks for your answer. I think I can manage à COM component. Do you mean a .net component that would work as a connector and manage read write and de serialization to xls /vba ? I could use protobuf-net for that

Comment: @Tom indeed; depending on what the data is (which I don't know), you could have the .NET component return a delimited string of the data in string form, or maybe some kind of array (depending on what works well from VBA)